# Setting Initial State from Axios in Vuex

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I'm currently still learning vue 2 and vuex, right now I'm testing on how to set an initial state from an API with axios. From my understanding, the initial state will always be an empty object, but using beforemount option on the component to execute the initState action and startState mutation, changes the state with whatever the API response data is, right? But for some reason, the mapGetter in my code returns undefined. Again, I'm still learning so maybe there's some stupid mistake that I did that makes the code didn't work.. so any input will be appreciated!

Below is my code:

TodoModule.js

```
import axios from "axios";

    const state = {};

    const getters = {
        allTodos: state => state.todos
    };

    const actions = {
        async initState({commit}) {
            await axios.get(`https://mockapi.io/api/todo/v1/endpoint`)
            .then((res) => {commit('startState', res.data)})
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
        }
    };

    const mutations = {
        startState: (state, payload) => state.todos = payload
    };

    export default {
        state,
        getters,
        actions,
        mutations
    }
```

Store(Index.js)

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Vue from 'vue';
import TodoModule from './modules/TodoModule.js';

// Load vuex
Vue.use(Vuex);

// Create store
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        TodoModule
    }
});
```

TodoApp.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Vuex Todo App</h3>
    <div class="todos">
      <div class="todo" v-for="todo in allTodos" :key="todo.id">
        {{ todo.name }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters} from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: "TodoApp",
  beforeMount(){
    this.$store.dispatch("initState");
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["allTodos"])
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png"> -->
    <!-- <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/> -->
    <TodoApp />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import TodoApp from './components/TodoApp.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    // HelloWorld,
    TodoApp
}
}
</script>
  body {
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    background: #e8f7f0;
  }
  .container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
  }
<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Here's a screenshot from Vue Devtools extension from Mozilla:

[image: Vue Devtools]

So the state actually successfully changed with the new data from API response, but for some reason the mapGetter is undefined.. and therefore the data cannot be loaded on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define in your state the todos key with your initial value (E.g. null or [ ] for an array).

```
const state = {
    todos: []
};
```

If you do this, your getter should work properly (they certainly use a Proxy under the hood to check changes so you need your key to exist in the state property)!

Comment: ohh so that's what I've been missing! tysm this helped me a lot